# unintended autonomous changing a1 / r1c1 notation in vba excel 2010

Tags: excel, vba

i have an excel/vba issue which seems to occur in excel2010 but not excel2016. for me it is a non comprehensible conversion between a1 and r1c1 notation.

i have a range that is dynamic

```
Dim rng As Range
rng = Application.Range("worksheet!A4:A" & _
      Worksheets("worksheet").Range("A" & rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

also i have a name-variable (called "Norm") i use as a dropdown option in cells and would like to update it according to the dynamic range using

```
With Application.Names("Norm")
    .Name = "Norm"
    .RefersTo = rng.Address
    .Comment = ""
End With
```

both run on Workbook_BeforeSave.

when saving while in vba editing mode everything works as expected, the name-variable has the correct range in a1-notation and the content of Norm is according to the range.

but saving in pure excel-mode results in the range in r1c1-notation which can not be processed by the name-variable leaving it empty. unfortunately i can't find any explanation or solution for that. is this an excel2010 issue or what can i do about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Range is a member of worksheet.
2. Names us a member of workbook.
3. You Set a range object.
4. RefersTo should point to the range object, not its address.

Revised code:

```
Dim rng As Range

WITH THISWORKBOOK.WORKSHEETS("worksheet")
    SET rng = .Range(.cells(4, "a"), .cells(.rows.count, "a").end(xlup))
end with

With thisworkbook.Names("Norm")
    .Name = "Norm"    'totally redundant, it already has a name identified in the line above
    .RefersTo = rng   'no address, just rng
    .Comment = ""
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

`Name` has two properties `RefersTo` and `RefersToR1C1`, which means that you should assign appropriate address style. If you want to be sure you get correct notation, you should use `ReferenceStyle` parameter:

```
Names("Norm").RefersTo = "=" & Range("A1").Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlA1)
Names("Norm").RefersToR1C1 = "=" & Range("A1").Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)
```

Comment: thank you! i tried this as well but it did not affect the issue. useful information though!

Answer (score 1):

First, you are not setting your `rng` object correctly:

```
rng = Application.Range("worksheet!A4:A" & _
      Worksheets("worksheet").Range("A" & rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

should give you an error, you need to `Set` your `rng` object, see code below:

```
Dim Sht As Worksheet
Dim Rng As Range, LastRow As Long

' set the worksheet object
Set Sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("worksheet")

With Sht
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row ' get last row with data in column A

    ' set the Range object
    Set Rng = .Range("A4:A" & LastRow)
End With

' updating the range that "Norm" refres to
With ThisWorkbook.Names("Norm")
    .RefersTo = Rng
End With
```

Comment: thank you! i had no idea how to adress the range object properly. i chose the answer by @user10847676 because it is more compact. but i would upvote yours as well if i were allowed to.